# execute_script() doesn't work in python with selenium phantomjs

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://global.ahnlab.com/site/securitycenter/securityinsight/securityInsightList.do')
driver.execute_script("getView('2218')")

html_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

print(soup.h1.string)
```

When I use Firefox(), the result is [AhnLab Puts in Appearance at RSAConference for 4th Straight Year] that I want.
But when I use PhanthomJS(), the result is [Security Insight] that I don't want.

If I use PhantomJS(), I can't get the result that I want?
I want to get the first result using a headless browser.

thanks.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phantomjs driver is not loading the navigation after the javascript call immediately. Just put a sleep of 5-10 seconds after the javascript call and it should work for you.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://global.ahnlab.com/site/securitycenter/securityinsight/securityInsightList.do')
driver.execute_script("getView('2218')")

# Introduce a sleep of 5 seconds here
time.sleep(5)

html_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

print(soup.h1.string)
```